# How do I get the users real uid if the program is run with sudo?

Tags: c, ubuntu

The program I am running needs root privledges and therefore is run with `sudo`, but it also needs to know what user is running it. `getuid` and `geteuid` both return `root`. How do I get the actual users username (or uid)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sudo` provides some environment variables to help you with exactly this case:

```
   SUDO_UID        Set to the user ID of the user who invoked
                   sudo

   SUDO_USER       Set to the login of the user who invoked sudo
```

steveayre has pointed out in the comments that the user can set these environment variables in some cases; the `sudo(8)` manpage includes in part:

```
The sudoers policy subjects variables
passed on the command line to the same restrictions as normal
environment variables with one important exception.  If the
setenv option is set in sudoers, the command to be run has the
SETENV tag set or the command matched is ALL, the user may set
variables that would otherwise be forbidden.  See sudoers(5)
for more information.
```

So be sure that you don't grant `ALL` commands to users when you need to rely upon this feature.

Comment: i really hate using environment variables, is there another way? (the main reason i hate using them is because they arent reliable: from a security POV or a compatability POV)

Comment: The environment variables should be safe to trust -- you must completely trust `sudo` in order to use it in this fashion. Any attack against `sudo` that allows marginally-trusted users to execute programs with modified environment variables is going to bring focus from dozens of security teams around the world to fix the flaw (or remove the feature if it cannot be fixed). As for compatibility, this is more portable than the other option I just thought of -- answered separately for its own comments. And this is probably safer than writing your own setuid-root program.

Comment: The security problem that I am referring to comes from either other programs running on the system or plugin-code which can both modify environment variables. But seeing as how the other solution doesnt work, I'll probably end up going with this and caching the variable myself on program startup (so hopefully noone will modify it before then).

Comment: Only processes with `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability will be able to attach to the executing program -- user processes won't have that capability -- and modify the environment variable. Processes with `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` are already able to do vast amounts of damage regardless of this environment variable. :)

Comment: The user can still override the SUDO_USER environment variable:

`$ sudo SUDO_USER=fake env | grep ^SUDO_USER` gives `SUDO_USER=fake`

Comment: @steveayre -- well this is frustrating. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A Linux-specific `audit_getloginuid()` function provided by the auditing system may be able to help; since `pam_loginuid(8)` is only going to be installed for the "main" daemons (`sshd`, `login`, `gdm`, etc.) the audit uid will remain unchanged when `sudo(8)` executes.

This will require a little configuration; add:

```
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
```

to the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file -- and whichever other services you allow your users to use.

Ensure `pam_loginuid.so` isn't loaded in the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` configuration file.

Comment: great idea, but it doesnt work: `audit_getloginuid()` returns -1.

Comment: Ah, silly me, assuming it was already configured; my Ubuntu 11.04 doesn't have `pam_loginuid` loaded by default. I edited my post to include a line to load the `pam_loginuid` module for `sshd` -- if you want it to work for GUI, console, or elsewhere, you'll have to load the PAM module in the corresponding services.

Answer (score 2):

You have two good choices...

1. Trust sudo and just use its environment
2. Make your program setuid-on-execution and then geteuid, et al, will work just fine

*Update:*

**[The setuid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)** is an access right flag in the file mode that causes a program to run with the capabilities of the executable file's owner. This is how sudo(1) is able to run things as root ... the sudo program itself has this mode.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-r-s--x--x  1 root  wheel  272384 Jun 22  2009 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

To make a program setuid root one might:

```
$ chown root a.out
$ chmod +s a.out
```

Needless to say, setuid root programs should be written carefully. You can setuid to a less privileged user if all you need is access to a protected directory or file.

Comment: `setuid-on-execution` can you explain that?

Answer (score 1):

The easier way would be using Who am i

```
who am i | awk '{print $1}'
```

or

```
who am i | cut -f1 -d" "
```