# Request root access programmatically

Tags: c, linux, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically gain root privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483755/how-to-programmatically-gain-root-privileges)

Is there any way to request root access programmatically to user in C over linux ?

I'm using raw sockets so it is needed root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to make your program suid-root, and have the first two lines of `main` open the raw socket and drop root.

This is still less than ideal from a security standpoint, since:

1. A compromise later in the program would give an attacker access to a raw socket, which could be used for many malicious purposes, possibly obtaining sufficient information to elevate privilege.
2. Any suid-root binary could be subject to vulnerabilities from flaws in the dynamic linker or startup code that runs before `main`. While these have become increasingly rare, even last year one was found again in glibc's linker using `LD_AUDIT` stuff. Many security-conscious systems (e.g. Openwall Linux) ban suid-root binaries completely for this reason.

A safer but more complex approach would be to have your program run as a daemon with elevated (but still minimal) privileges, and have the CLI interface be just a trivial wrapper that communicates with the daemon over a unix socket via a trivial protocol that can be mechanically checked for vulnerabilities.