# How to run print command lpr -p programmatically throgh root privilage in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, printing, root-access

I want to run print command `lpr -p` programmatically through root privilege in Qt.  Actually I want to print the pdf file using these command. This command is working through terminal but not through programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the code where you try this?

Comment: There is a good answer on how to gain root using capabilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483755/how-to-programmatically-gain-root-privileges

Comment: You should not need root privilege to run `lpr`, and you might want to use `lp` instead of `lpr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run commands that need root privilege by running :

```
echo myPass | sudo -S lpr -p
```

Although it's not a good idea to echo your password in shell but you can do it in Qt via `Qprocess` like :

```
QProcess process1;
QProcess process2;

process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);

process1.start("echo myPass");
process2.start("sudo -S lpr -p");
process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);


process2.waitForFinished(3000);
```

Comment: Nejat..Actually I am using fedora 17 and it doesn't support sudo.