# C++ Create file in write protected directory

Tags: c++, c++11, unix

In my C++ program I download images (album art etc.) from over the air radio signals and need to save the images in a public web folder such as `/var/www/html` to serve later via a web page.

I'm developing on Ubuntu 16.04 but eventually, the app will be deployed on Raspberry Pi. My program is a WebSocket Server using the library [uWebsockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) and also talks to a radio tuner via unix sockets. The app is supposed to auto-start at boot time and act as WebSocket server on a specific port.

Here's the code to save the image array -

```
    std::string filePath = "/var/www/html/output1.jpg";
    std::ofstream ofs(filePath);
    ofs.write(image->c_str(), image->size()); // image is JPEG image as string array
    ofs.flush();
    ofs.close();
```

Above code won't create file at the specified location, however it will work if the path is just `"output1.jpg"`.

Clearly, my app doesn't have permission to write to `/var/www/html`. Is there any way to solve this using standard c++ or boost?

Thanks

Comment: You have to run the app from an account that has the correct permissions.

Comment: You can only write to directories to which the running process has access permissions. Unless you make the user of your programm give credentials for a user who *has* such permissions, there is nothing any programming library can, or indeed, **should be able to** do. That would be a security vulnerability.

Comment: Ok, above code won't create file. Any errors?

Comment: No errors, but no file will be create either. Program runs ok.

Comment: @kaushal You probably do have errors but you do not check for them.

Comment: Try `if(!ofs) std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` after opening the file.

Comment: Did you try to use filePath like \\\var\\www\\html\\output1.jpg?

Comment: @Galik, I meant the program didn't crash or anything like that. Yes, I didn't check the  code, but I knew it doesn't create the file because of permissions

Comment: @SvSv this is on Ubuntu/Linux

Comment: If there was a way to circumvent the permissions programatically then Lunux would be full of viruses. Linux developers put a lot of effort into making it impossible to do what you are asking. Virus writers look for flaws in their programming to exploit in an effort to do what you want to do.

Comment: Can you create a file in that directory manually? Like "touch /var/www/html/output1.jpg"

Comment: @Galik I understand. No, I don't want to circumvent anything here :). I just want to be able to save the files there and if it's possible pragmatically. My application requires me to save files to serve via web page later. But It seems like it is not possible by design then.

Comment: You can save files in a temp folder, and then just copy them, using OS API.

Comment: @kaushal If you don’t have permission to do it, but want to do it anyway, then you *do* want to circumvent the thing that doesn’t let you. If you own the computer you can (once, not programmatically) go in and change directory permissions with `chmod`, or you can run this program as the appropriate user.

Comment: There are two ways you could move forward. Either run your program as the user that runs the web-server or configure the web-server to access a folder in your home directory with your permissions.

Comment: You may want to invest your time looking at the code for many existing web-based applications that read and write files, and how they work within the confines of the underlying operating system security model.

Comment: @DevSolar This is an example of a question asking for a security vulneratility to solve a practical problem.  In order to answer it we need more information about the host OS and system.  It is also an X/Y problem.

Comment: @Galik Got the error `Permission denied` as expected with your code above.

Comment: Added more details about the host

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483755/how-to-programmatically-gain-root-privileges