# Implement sudo su in a C program

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I writing a program that is used by a parent process. I cannot control the parent process, its  permissions, and how it runs my process.

My program runs a device that needs root permissions, while the parent process does not have the corresponding permissions.

Tried to use setuid(0); setgid(0); in my program. Also, tried to add the user of the process to use sudo. In addition, I run the solutions below. Does not works

The code

```
if(dry_run == 0)
{
    PRINT("reached here\n");
    ret =  ioctl((int64_t)device, NVME_IOCTL, &usr_io_cmd);
}

if (ret != 0 ) {
    PRINT("ERROR : error %x returned\n", ret);
    PRINT( "%s\n",strerror(errno) );
```

Where PRINT prints to a log file.

The log file

[2019-09-05 14:27:25] reached here

[2019-09-05 14:27:25] ERROR  : error ffffffff returned

[2019-09-05 14:27:25] Operation not permitted

What can my program do? How can I implement "sudo su" in my program? Is there an alternative solution?

Edit: why this question is locked? I tried the solutions below and it did not worked.

Comment: why is the question downgraded? :(

Comment: Not my DV, but you haven't shown much effort that you made to solve the problem. Consider adding the code that you've tried for starters.

Comment: @user3563894 You haven't shown what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Done. Described what I tried to do and failed.

Comment: Don't describe your code - post it.

Comment: Done. Now the code is published

Comment: Current **close reason** ("recommendation") is actually **bad**: It should be a "duplicate" for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483755/how-to-programmatically-gain-root-privileges or other similar question. And, according to answers to that question, the code isn't required for your question: gaining root privileges cannot be done *programmatically*, the only way is to set SUID or GUID bits for your executable.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to have your program have the [*setuid* or *setgid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit set in the *file permissions*. This will cause the running process to have the *effective* user id of that of the program owner (setuid) or effective gid that of the program group (gid). You then can perform actions as those identities or *become* those with `setuid` and `setgid`.

`sudo su` is a cargo-cult way of doing things - *both* are programs that more or less do the same thing - elevate permissions of an unprivileged caller.

I.e. to have the program `foo` owned by root with setuid bit set, you'd do:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo
sudo chown root:root foo
sudo chmod 4755 foo
```

Comment: Tried to do setuid(0); setuid(0);. It does not works. The device will only succeed if doing "sudo command_to_device"

Comment: @user3563894 you didn't set the *setuid bit in the file permissions'

Comment: `sudo su` does start a shell. But a better way to do that would be `sudo -i`.

Comment: Tried to do these operations over the code I wrote. does not works